# Updating progress bar when method inside BackgroundWorker cycles

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, progress-bar, backgroundworker

First off here's my code layout:

```
public partial class GUI : Form
{
    public GUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BigMethod bigMeth = new BigMethod();
        bigMeth.begin();
    }

    public void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar.Refresh();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
}

public class BigMethod()
// If it matters, BigMethod() is in a separate .cs file in the same namespace
{
public void begin()
    {
for (; time <= 3600; time += T_STEP)       //  Running for 1 hour
        {

            //**********************************************
            //  DO FOR EACH TIMESTEP
            //**********************************************

            // Stuff

            //**********************************************
            //  Report back
            //**********************************************
            gui.backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(time / RUNTIME * 100));
            //gui.progressBar.Value = (int)(time / RUNTIME * 100);

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            timeCounter += T_STEP;

        }   // End Loop
}
}
```

So I have a method called BigMethod() in a separate class that contains a very large, math intensive loop that takes around 15 seconds to complete. Right now I have a button that asynchronously runs a BackgroundWorker containing the giant BigMethod(). This is working quite well as far as I can tell, the method does exactly what it's supposed to without "crashing" the GUI.

Problem is, the progressBar is not refreshing. (Every time the loop inside BigMethod() completes it recomputes a progress and reports back to backgroundWorker). The property progressBar.Value is updating fine, Debug.WriteLine(progressBar.Value) displays exactly what it should, a 0-100 smooth increase, however the actual progressBar does not move nor does it jump to 100 upon completion.

Everything works fine if I cut BigMethod and place it inside the _DoWork, but that isn't an option as it heavily fragments the code layout.

What can I do to fix this? I've already tried progressBar.Refresh() and progressBar.Update()  but they don't do anything.

As you can probably tell, I'm brand new to threading so there's probably something obvious I'm missing here but I just can't see it. How do you update the progressBar from somewhere outside its class?

Comment: So you are passing in `backgroundWorker1` into the `BigMethod` function?  Can you post the loop (or slimmed down version) of the loop that calls `ReportProgress`?  My initial guess is you are calling it too often and it doesnt have time to udpdate

Comment: An easy quick test to see if its being called too often is to put a sleep in `giant loop start`.  So just add `Thread.Sleep(2000)` and see if it updates progress

Comment: Adding a Thread.Sleep(2000) appeared to have no effect on the draw. Value is still updating correctly. I've added what the loop is. Basically it's a giant for() loop that reports back at each increment.

Comment: Can you show how do you pass gui variable to BigMethod ? I tried your example and passed backgroundWorker1 to begin method public void begin(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1) and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

The `backgroundWorker` is on a different thread than the GUI thread. You have to check if you're on the GUI thread by looking at `InvokeRequired` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx). If you aren't, invoke the function on the GUI thread by calling `Invoke()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx).

This code snippet should do the trick.

```
public void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<object, ProgressChangedEventArgs>(backgroundWork1_ProgressChanged), sender, e);
        return;
    }
    this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```